# Using content-disposition with LWP::UserAgent on a Google Drive document

Tags: perl, http-headers, wget, lwp, content-disposition

I'm trying to save a Google Drive shared file using its actual filename received from the server (content-disposition):

I tried to analyze the header:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use LWP::UserAgent qw( );
my $str = 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6vqTWO9kmdmdzk5ejhDSXgzMDg/view?usp=sharing';
$str =~ /file\/d\/(\w+)/;
my $url = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id='.$1;
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
my $response = $ua->head($url)->{'_headers'};
print Dumper( $response );
```

I got this:

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
'client-ssl-cert-subject' => '/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=*.googleusercontent.com',
'connection' => 'close',
'date' => 'Mon, 19 Oct 2015 14:45:45 GMT',
'content-type' => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
'x-guploader-uploadid' => 'AEnB2UrQJIoJUIIhWnKz9HAlW_2XKApLe_0IDMZjS0gGQOMdRaF68Od2xsxssp7mBdQP9kNrjvDueWUP5pSa1eHbprSjbPvfbA',
'alternate-protocol' => '443:quic,p=1',
'expires' => 'Mon, 19 Oct 2015 14:45:45 GMT',
'::std_case' => {
   'client-ssl-socket-class' => 'Client-SSL-Socket-Class',
   'client-ssl-cert-subject' => 'Client-SSL-Cert-Subject',
   'client-ssl-cipher' => 'Client-SSL-Cipher',
   'client-peer' => 'Client-Peer',
   'x-guploader-uploadid' => 'X-GUploader-UploadID',
   'alternate-protocol' => 'Alternate-Protocol',
   'alt-svc' => 'Alt-Svc',
   'client-ssl-cert-issuer' => 'Client-SSL-Cert-Issuer',
   'client-date' => 'Client-Date',
   'client-response-num' => 'Client-Response-Num'
 },
'client-ssl-cert-issuer' => '/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2',
'server' => 'UploadServer',
'client-date' => 'Mon, 19 Oct 2015 14:45:55 GMT',
'client-ssl-socket-class' => 'IO::Socket::SSL',
'client-ssl-cipher' => 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256',
'client-peer' => '2a00:1450:400c:c08::84:443',
'alt-svc' => 'quic=":443"; p="1"; ma=604800',
'cache-control' => 'private, max-age=0',
'client-response-num' => 1
}, 'HTTP::Headers' );
```

I expected to find the content-disposition header within the above.
On the other hand, wget correctly gives the filename:

```
#wget --content-disposition "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B6vqTWO9kmdmdzk5ejhDSXgzMDg"
--2015-10-19 20:21:37--  https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B6vqTWO9kmdmdzk5ejhDSXgzMDg
Resolving drive.google.com (drive.google.com)... 2a00:1450:400c:c04::64, 74.125.206.139, 74.125.206.101, ...
Connecting to drive.google.com (drive.google.com)|2a00:1450:400c:c04::64|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://doc-0s-2s-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/ha0ro937gcuc7l7deffksulhg5h7mbp1/unidk5uvfpl9kut1rl3hb5lqcvis8vdq/1445263200000/06380472059566149580/*/0B6vqTWO9kmdmdzk5ejhDSXgzMDg?e=download [following]
Warning: wildcards not supported in HTTP.
--2015-10-19 20:21:37--  https://doc-0s-2s-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/ha0ro937gcuc7l7deffksulhg5h7mbp1/unidk5uvfpl9kut1rl3hb5lqcvis8vdq/1445263200000/06380472059566149580/*/0B6vqTWO9kmdmdzk5ejhDSXgzMDg?e=download
Resolving doc-0s-2s-docs.googleusercontent.com (doc-0s-2s-docs.googleusercontent.com)... 2a00:1450:400c:c08::84, 74.125.140.132
Connecting to doc-0s-2s-docs.googleusercontent.com (doc-0s-2s-docs.googleusercontent.com)|2a00:1450:400c:c08::84|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 16 [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘testdoc.txttestdoc.txt’

testdoc.txttestdoc.txt                              100%[====================================================================================================================>]      16  --.-KB/s   in 0s

2015-10-19 20:21:38 (550 KB/s) - ‘testdoc.txttestdoc.txt’ saved [16/16]
```

How can I get the correct filename from the server using perl?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but you can also get good LWP debugging info via https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::ConsoleLogger::Easy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that you're not doing a `HEAD` with wget. If you look at the status of the response in your Perl code you're getting

```
503 Service Unavailable
```

which could refer to many things, but in this case means that `HEAD` isn't supported. Change that for a `GET` and all is well

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';

use LWP::UserAgent;

my $str = 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6vqTWO9kmdmdzk5ejhDSXgzMDg/view?usp=sharing';
die unless $str =~ m{file/d/(\w+)};

my $url = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=$1";

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

my $resp = $ua->get($url);

say $resp->status_line;

say $resp->header('Content-Disposition');
```

#### output

```
200 OK
attachment;filename="testdoc.txt";filename*=UTF-8''testdoc.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the difference is this:

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://doc-0s-2s-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/ha0ro937gcuc7l7deffksulhg5h7mbp1/unidk5uvfpl9kut1rl3hb5lqcvis8vdq/1445263200000/06380472059566149580/*/0B6vqTWO9kmdmdzk5ejhDSXgzMDg?e=download [following]
```

Your initial URL is getting redirected - so the thing you're getting headers for, isn't the file `wget` is downloading. Try reading the `status_line` off your head request, and see what you get.